# ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './depot/' (errno: 13)

Tags: mysql

I want to use of symbolic link for change path database in mysql.
I create a Directory ,then create a symbolic link to this directory but when I want to use of this database get following error:

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './depot/' (errno: 13)
```

I disabled apparmor but not working.

I checked No Problem of Permission.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem you need to set correct permission on `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/ 

mysql -u user -p dbname -e 'show tables;'
```